# MySQL Multiple Table Join

Tags: mysql, distinct, join

I have a 3 tables that I'm trying to join and get distinct results.

```
CREATE TABLE  `car` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

mysql> select * from car;

+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | acura | 
+----+-------+




CREATE TABLE  `tires` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tire_desc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `car_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `new_fk_constraint` (`car_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `new_fk_constraint` FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `car` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB

mysql> select * from tires;

+----+-------------+--------+
| id | tire_desc   | car_id |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 | front_right |      1 | 
|  2 | front_left  |      1 | 
+----+-------------+--------+


CREATE TABLE  `lights` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lights_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `car_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `new1_fk_constraint` (`car_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `new1_fk_constraint` FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `car` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB

mysql> select * from lights;

+----+-------------+--------+
| id | lights_desc | car_id |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 | right_light |      1 | 
|  2 | left_light  |      1 | 
+----+-------------+--------+
```

Here is my query.

```
mysql> SELECT name, group_concat(tire_desc), group_concat(lights_desc)
FROM car 
left join tires on car.id = tires.car_id 
left join lights on car.id = car_id 
group by car.id;

+-------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| name  | group_concat(tire_desc)                       | group_concat(lights_desc)                     |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| acura | front_right,front_right,front_left,front_left | right_light,left_light,right_light,left_light | 
+-------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I get duplicate entires and this is what I would like to get.

```
+-------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| name  | group_concat(tire_desc) | group_concat(lights_desc) |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| acura | front_right,front_left | right_light,left_light | 
+-------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

I cannot use distinct in group_concat because I might have legitimate duplicates which I would like to keep.  Is there any way to do this query using joins and not using inner selects like the statement below?

```
SELECT name, 
(select group_concat(tire_desc) from tires where car.id = tires.car_id), 
(select group_concat(lights_desc) from lights where car.id = lights.car_id)
FROM car
```

Also, if I will use inner selects, will there be any performance issues over joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this query using joins and not using inner selects like the statement below?

There is, but not as efficient and can omit some intended duplicates:

```
SELECT name, group_concat(DISTINCT tire_desc), group_concat(DISTINCT lights_desc)
FROM car 
left join tires on car.id = tires.car_id 
left join lights on car.id = car_id 
group by car.id;
```

> Also, if I will use inner selects, will there be any performance issues over joins?

In your very case, yes: the subselects will be faster.

On `MyISAM` tables, in some cases the subselects tend to be faster than `GROUP BY` queries, due to the fact that `GROUP BY` in `MyISAM` is quite expensive due to sorting / materialization overhead:

- [**Aggregates: subqueries vs. GROUP BY**](http://explainextended.com/2010/01/30/aggregates-subqueries-vs-group-by/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to specify which car_id you mean in the second ON

```
SELECT name, group_concat(tire_desc), group_concat(lights_desc)
FROM car 
left join tires on car.id = tires.car_id 
left join lights on car.id = **lights**.car_id 
group by car.id;
```

I believe joins are faster than subqueries on InnoDB tables.